# JS error after setAttribute on SVG element is not catchable

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am working on a web tool, which lets you change attributes of SVG elements. Currently I am trying to give the user feedback on any invalid attributes or values.

When calling setAttribute (or setAttributeNS) on an SVG element with an unexpected value, a javascript error occurs. I tried to catch this by using try/catch or window.onerror, but could not find a way to do so.

Example code:

```html
    <svg id="svg" width="300" height="100">
      <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="10" y1="10" x2="100" y2="100">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#000000"></stop>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#969695"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
    </svg>
```

```js
    try {
       document.querySelector('#gradient').setAttribute('x1', 'This error is not catchable');
    } catch (error) {
       console.log('never triggered');
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wr3tne2y/

tested in Chromium v91 and firefox:

[image: js error slipping through try/catch]

Comment: I think the browser expects a number instead of text at html element `linearGradient`

Comment: I am aware that the attribute's value is wrong. what I am trying to do is, to catch such errors and give proper feedback to the user.

Comment: for some reason, the fiddle is working fine for me.

Comment: This is an internal message to the developer that it's wrong. The attribute is still set to that value i.e. you can call getAttribute and get the text, it's just that the linearGradient will use its default x1 value and not the value you've set.

Comment: You can verify there is no error by setting ``x1`` from the console

Comment: I see - so its not a javascript error? can you think of a way to catch it none the less? at some point the browser knows about it. it would help the user immensely if they knew about invalid attributes.

Comment: Correct. This is not a JS error, this is a warning that the SVG renderer considers that value an error.  I don't believe there is a way to check for the error after the fact. You would need to check the value before you set it.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to check the value before setting it.

```
let val = 'This error is not catchable';
if (!isNaN(parseInt(val, 10)))
{
  document.querySelector('#gradient').setAttribute('x1', val);
}
else
{
  console.log('ERROR!');
}
```

Comment: the gradient attribute only accepting numbers was just an example. as described in my use-case above, the user enters both an attribute and a value and is currently not aware of any wrong-doing because I cannot detect such errors. I cannot manually check all possible values - because setting things like `x1="calc(40 + 240)"` would actually work. therefor I would need a generic solution to programmatically detect such errors and inform the user of invalid values.

Comment: Unless each browser has a method to detect errors that I don't know about, there is no generic method.  You would need to write a validator for each type of attribute.  There are not that many attribute types. So you wouldn't need to write a lot of them. For instance, almost all size and position attributes could share a generic "SVGLength" validator.  But some of those will need additional checks, for instance, negative values are invalid for some length attributes.  Refer to the spec for attribute value restrictions.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I also tried this approach first, but think of attributes like transform or style which alone offer way too many options to check accordingly. then add any calculating functions like (calc, clamp, min, max etc..).

Comment: if you could provide any source that says that this is not an actual JS error, I'll be happy to accept that answer. (given your reputation, I would also accept you as source if you put it in an answer :) )

Comment: If the `try/catch` isn't catching it, then it isn't a JS error.  The other reason I know that is that it is not a JS error to set an DOM element attribute to an illegal value.  All you are doing is setting a string attribute to have a string value. It's not even a DOM error, because the DOM doesn't know what the contents of that string are supposed to be. It is only the SVG parser and renderer that care what that value is. So we can assume that it is simply a helpful warning coming from the SVG subsystem.